# Custom method annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations, jersey

I am trying to write a annotation `@HasAccess`for a role based check for certain method.

e.g.

```
@Path("/$count")
@GET
@HasAccess(Role.CASHIER)
public String getCount() {
    //....
}
```

So I found couple of example using spring and jersey but I am unable to find something that is generic and independent of framework because I want to write this annotation independent of framework and can be used anywhere.

How can I implement the annotation so that it is processed before the call reached to method and AOP is not an option for me .

Any pointers ?

Comment: It's not easy. First get really familiar with reflection. Then get familiar with dynamic proxies. Then put it together to build your own framework. There's no java magic with annotations. It's all up the implementor of a framework on how to process the annotations.

Comment: what jersey version are you using?

Comment: We are using 1.19